# Convert Float to Time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to convert a DataFrame series with floats like "1200" into 12:00:00.

My initial DataFrame is this one:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1200.0, 0.0, 1536.0, 1530.0, 0.0], columns=['Occurred Time'])
print(df)
```

```
   Occurred Time
0         1200.0
1            0.0
2         1536.0
3         1530.0
4            0.0
```

I am trying to convert the "Occurred Time" float from 1200.0 to 12:00:00.

I used this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1200.0, 0.0, 1536.0, 1530.0, 0.0], columns=['Occurred Time'])
df['Occurred Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Occurred Time'])
print(df)
```

but it does not work and the output is this:

```
                  Occurred Time
0 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001200
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001536
3 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001530
4 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
```

I don't know what to do!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: A float like `1536.0` - is that `15:36` or is that hundreths of a minute, so `15:21`?

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you convert to strings, pad with zeros and provide a format to [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Occurred Time'].astype(int)
                            .astype(str).str.zfill(4),
                            format='%H%M')
```

Output:

```
   Occurred Time                time
0           1200 1900-01-01 12:00:00
1              0 1900-01-01 00:00:00
2           1536 1900-01-01 15:36:00
```

Add `.dt.time` if you want only the time:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Occurred Time'].astype(int)
                            .astype(str).str.zfill(4),
                            format='%H%M').dt.time
```

Output:

```
   Occurred Time      time
0           1200  12:00:00
1              0  00:00:00
2           1536  15:36:00
```